# Cmake Cross Compiling causing a test failure on arm-none-eabi-gcc

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, arm

I am trying to use cmake in a way to cross compile to arm cortex-m. I have setup cmake with the following CMakeLists.txt file.

```
INCLUDE(CMakeForceCompiler)
#cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
#added as test
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

#specify the generator to use
SET(CMAKE_GENERATOR "Unix Makefiles")
project(Template C CXX)
```

However, when I run "cmake .." fro the build directory or from the gui. I get the follwing error.

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.3/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61
>   (message):   The C compiler "C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU Tools ARM
>   Embedded/4.9   2014q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe" is not able to
>   compile a simple test   program.

Why is cmake trying to test the compiler? How do I make it stop? 
I tried use NONE as the language, but then it doesnt know the link language. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER` macro [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CMakeForceCompiler.html):

> It sets CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the given compiler and the cmake internal variable CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID to the given compiler-id. It also bypasses the check for working compiler and basic compiler information tests.

Comment: Yes, it "should" do that, however, when I go to the command line, navigate to the build directory, and run "cmake .." it does the compiler check. Hence "SET(CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)". The other set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER) was a test that I forgot to erase before posting.

Comment: What exact code you use with `CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER` as a macro?

Comment: Everything in my CMakeLists.txt file is above. The exact line is SET(CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc).

Comment: Such a way you set variable, not a macro. Macro usage should be like `CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(<compiler> <compiler-id>)`.

Comment: ...I'm dense... Thanks for that.